# How can I create a ram root disk for pxeboot of xen dom0?

Tags: xen, pxe-boot, syslinux

I've been able to successfully boot a xen kernel and dom0 by setting up things according to this link:

http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Mboot.c32

However, I'm wanting my root partition not to be local, and not an NFS root.

What I am wanting instead it to be my customized disk image. Downloaded and placed into ram.  Now I do have a disk image mostly made up.  But I'm at a loss as to how to set up mboot to make that the root.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

And the answer which I've found works well is to use tinycorelinux as a starting point.

As this runs in ram by default and is very small.  Ideal for pxeboot situations.